# Elasticsearch: prefer keyword or integer datatype for for fields mainly used in aggregations?

Tags: performance, elasticsearch, types

The Elasticsearch [performance tuning guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/tune-for-search-speed.html) states:

*The fact that some data is numeric does not mean it should always be mapped as a numeric field. The way that Elasticsearch indexes numbers optimizes for range queries while keyword fields are better at term queries. Typically, fields storing identifiers such as an ISBN or any number identifying a record from another database are rarely used in range queries or aggregations. **This is why they might benefit from being mapped as keyword rather than as integer or long.***

However, this leaves ambiguity about **what datatype to choose for numeric data that will only feature in aggregations?**

For example, fields populated from a Java enum should be stored using their ordinal value (if you care more about performance than readability). But that still leaves you two options: store them as either 0, 1, 2, ... (integer) or as "0", "1", "2", ... (keyword).

If I am going to aggregate often on such a field, while not using it that much in term queries, which of the two options should I go for from a performance perspective?

Comment: Are you going to use this field in range query, use this field to sort the results? If the answer to any of this is yes then you should use integer/long data type.
Even in case you want your aggregation buckets to be sort by key ( this field ) and expect it to be sorted as numeric values then also you should use a numeric data type.

Comment: Thanks Nishant - but no, as I mentioned, the field is not going to be used for any type of query (range, term, etc.); just for aggregations. Sorting the buckets is neither of interest to me.So my question basically is: what datatype to prefer for aggregations if you have the choice? If your data is textual, you have no choice (it must be keyword). But if your data is numeric, you do.

Comment: If your data is numeric, use numeric datatypes. Simple. Otherwise your data model would not be correct. And even ends up being **fundamentally** flawed. Why would you go against the nature :). I don't like to go in details of what aggregations you may miss out, but take it like this, how would you perform certain numeric based metric based aggregations like `sum` if its a `keyword`. Leave performance aside over simplicity.

Comment: you would sum over the values _in_ a group, but that's independent of the datatype of the field you want to group on

Comment: *Sum over values in a group*, that's not traditional `sum`. *Independent of the datatype?* That's not correct. Why? Because "1"+"1" = "11" in text. Another example, if I have a sales document with price information, how would I sum the total sales done per day if price is a `keyword`? And if you can do via scripts(again converting it into integer/float), it isn't efficient. Integer, Long, Float are `fundamental` datatypes. I'm reiterating the point `fundamental` meaning they are not to be compromised.You are misunderstanding if `identifiers` are to be used as keyword or numbers.